# CSS3 animations - animating width of image

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I would like to shrink the size of an image when the mouse hovers over it. I would like to use CSS3 animations if possible. This is what I am currently doing:

```css
#logo-icon img { width: 80px; };
#logo-icon img:hover { width: 50px; transition: width 0.2s; };
```

When the mouse hovers over the image, instead of it transitioning from an 80px width to a 50px width, it is transitioning from a 0px width to a 50px width.

Is it possible to get it to transition from 80px to 50px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
#logo-icon img { width: 80px; transition: width 0.2s;};
#logo-icon img:hover { width: 50px;  };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CxU5g/